# CSS Error (maybe float) only on Macs and Only some of the time

Tags: css, safari

This issue has been very hard for me to debug.  I am a pc user and have only seen this error in screen shots.  If anyone can offer an opinion on how to fix, it would be greatly appreciated.  Please see site and screenshots below.

http://www.lostlettermen.com/cssissues.jpg

http://www.lostlettermen.com

Comment: I'm getting a Database Error screen when I'm trying to view the page now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's what I've gathered for you. Running the latest version of every tested browser, on 10.6.4. I wasn't able to reproduce any troubles on any browser on a Mac, even with multiple refreshes with cache-cleared.

### Firefox

[image: Looks fine]
It seems to work fine in Firefox, after multiple cache-free refreshes I can't reproduce your screenshot in Firefox. Everything appears aligned as I'd expect it to.

### Safari

[image: Looks fine]
Everything here looks just like Firefox, everything aligned, nothing floating weird, I can see what I'd expect. Multiple refreshes again did not create a problem.

### Chrome

[image]
I initially experienced an issue with everything moving up on Chrome, but that's because I have an ad-blocker. That's one thing that you may want to consider, as it causes everything on your page to shift up. Perhaps position the ad `div` absolute so if it's removed it doesn't influence the rest of the page.

Given that I'm having so much trouble reproducing this issue, you may want to find out what they're specifically running, and when they run into the issue.